# laravel 8 x-components in blades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I can't figure out the way x-blades are working in laravel.

**Example**

I've created custom `textarea` component but I can't get values of `rows` and `cols` from blade.

**Logic**

If blade provides `rows` & `cols` use that if not use static ones.

#### Code

`textarea.blade.php`

```
@props(['disabled' => false, 'rows' => '4', 'cols' => '50'])

<textarea {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} rows="{{ $rows ? $slot : $rows }}" cols="{{ $cols }}" {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-input rounded-md shadow-sm']) !!}></textarea>
```

`myform.blade.php`

```
<x-textarea class="block mt-1 w-full" name="address" rows="10" cols="3" />
```

**Testing results**

`cols="{{ $cols }}"` returning static value `50` from component

`rows="{{ $rows ? $slot : $rows }}"` returning `rows=""`

**any idea?**

Comment: The ternary `$rows ? $slot : $rows` looks wrong. It says "if `$rows` is truthy then `$slots` otherwise `$rows`" but in the otherwise part `$rows` is always falsy

Comment: @apokryfos please share your ideas

Comment: how about `$rows ?: $slot` ?

Comment: @apokryfos that just gets static ones from component

Comment: @apokryfos please be aware that i should use 2 `$slot` one for `rows` one for `cols`

Comment: According to [this|https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components] you need to pass properties as `:rows="10" :cols="3"` (if I'm reading this correctly) then your refer to them as `$rows` and `$columns`. You don't seem to be passing a slot here

Comment: @apokryfos I just tried that if I keep my static numbers it just print them, but if i remove them as `message` in docs shows then it returns `Undefined variable: rows`  https://ibb.co/C55Ycms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Here is how I did it:

`component`

```
@props(['disabled' => false, 'rows'=>'4', 'cols'=>'50'])

<textarea {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} rows="{{ $rows }}" cols="{{ $cols }}" {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-input rounded-md shadow-sm']) !!}></textarea>
```

`blade`

```
<x-textarea class="block mt-1 w-full" name="address" required :value="old('address')" >
  <x-slot name="cols">3</x-slot>
  <x-slot name="rows">10</x-slot>
</x-textarea>
```

Now if I remove `<x-slot name="cols">` and `<x-slot name="rows">` it uses static values from component, if not it uses my blades values.